# Adding missing pause time in timespan

Tags: database, mariadb

I have a table of "tracked times" that tracks worktimes and pauses logged by users. I now want to calculate how much pause-time I need to add in a timespan, based on allready existing pause.

E.g. I have a rule that says, that between 09:00 and 10:30 there needs to be at least 1 hour of pauses logged. If I allready have 15 Mintues of Pauses logged, I only need to log 45 more minutes (from 9:45 to 10:30).

The problem is, that the amount of time I need to add, influences which pauses count against the allready taken pause time:

E.g. I want 1 hour of pause between 9:00 and 10:30, and I allready have 15 Minutes of pause logged between 10:15 and 10:30. I would now need to add 1 hour of pause between 09:30 and 10:30 (since the added pause overlaps the allready taken pause).

Is there a way to calculate the missing pause time? (The current stack is php+larvel/eloquent + mariadb, but I'm mostly looking for a algorithm not a system-specific solution).

**Tables:**

tracked_times:

| id | from | to | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 08.08.2023 - 08:00:00 | 08.08.2023 - 10:00:00 | worktime |
| 2 | 08.08.2023 - 10:01:00 | 08.08.2023 - 10:15:00 | pause |
| 3 | 08.08.2023 - 10:16:00 | 08.08.2023 - 12:00:00 | worktime |

pause_rule:

| id | from | to | length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09:00:00 | 10:30:00 | 01:00:00 |

Any solution I can come up with involves approximating the result and then recursively repeating the calculation, which I would like to avoid if possible.